# Node.js command get error while using pgrep

Tags: node.js, exec, grep

In my code, I need to check if a program is started. To do so, I have a function 'running':

```
function running(app, callback) {
    var arg = 'pgrep --count ' + app;
    exec( arg, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error:' + inspect(err) + ' ' + stderr);
            callback('0');
        } else {
            var data = '' + stdout;
            callback(data.charAt(0)); //Will be 0 only if no app is started
        }
    });
}
```

It worked well for some times, but now I get:

```
Error: { [Error: Command failed: ]
[stack]: [Getter/Setter],
[arguments]:undefined,
[type]: undefined,
[message]: 'Command failed: ',
killed: false,
code: 1,
signal: null }
```

(stderr is empty)

I don t understand why and so can t think of any solution.

Does anyone could tell me why do I get this error?

Comment: You should probably dump stdout in your `if (err)` branch as well.

Comment: stdout is empty as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgrep` will return a non-zero status if there are no processes matching your request. Node will interpret this non-zero status as meaning that `pgrep` failed. This can easily be checked at the shell, by using `echo $?` which shows you the exit status of the previous command. Assuming you have some `bash` instances running

```
$ pgrep --count bash; echo $?
```

You'll see on the console the number of `bash` instance running and the exit code which will be `0`. Now, if you try with something that does not exist:

```
$ pgrep --count nonexistent; echo $?
```

You'll see a count of `0` and an exit status of `1`.

Here is what the man page for `pgrep` says about the exit status:

> ```
> EXIT STATUS
>     0      One or more processes matched the criteria.
>     1      No processes matched.
>     2      Syntax error in the command line.
>     3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
> ```

So you could check the result with something like this:

```
var count;
if (err) {
    if (err.code === 1)
        count = 0; // Status 1 means no match, so we don't have to parse anything.
    else {
        // Real error, fail hard...
    }
}
else {
    count = ... ; // parse count from stdout
}
callback(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arg = 'pgrep --count ' + app,
```

There are two issues here:

1. on Linux, it's not `--count` it's `-c`
2. that line should end with a `;`, not a comma.

Comment: Well, with those two chnages it works for me.  Is `pgrep` still in the path of the code being run?